# C# SSIS Object and String Issue

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm learning SSIS and have an OK understanding of C#. I have a variable (NumberRows) that has already counted all the rows in an excel spreadsheet. Now, I want to display a message saying that by using the MessageBox.Show method(?).

When I try doing:
`MessageBox.Show("There are {0} Finalists", Dts.Variables["NumberRows"].Value);`
I get an error saying "cannot convert from 'object' to string'".

I'm thinking to myself "that's fine, i'll just at a .ToString() at the end" like this:
`MessageBox.Show("There are {0} Finalists", Dts.Variables["NumberRows"].Value.ToString());`

The error goes away but the output reads "There are 0 Finalists". Then I change it to:
`MessageBox.Show("There are " + Dts.Variables["NumberRows"].Value + " Finalists");` Now it correctly shows "There are 109 Finalists"

My issue is solved, but I want to learn what my mistake was. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show` does not format strings, like `string.Format()` or `Console.WriteLine()`.

The [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s(v=vs.110).aspx) of `MessageBox.Show(String, String)` states that the two string parameters are for the text & caption of the window, with no mention of formatting.

To do what you were trying to do, you'll need to do this:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("There are {0} Finalists", Dts.Variables["NumberRows"].Value), "Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Overload List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) for `MessageBox.Show` you will not find an overload capable of handling what you are trying to do with your first two code snippets.

What happens is the following method `MessageBox.Show(string text, string caption)`, which should result in your SQL value being placed in the caption of the message box dialog window.